# How to extend an ASP.NET Core MVC project by Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently trying to extend an existing ASP.NET Core MVC project by a Razor page (since several tutorial videos claim that MVC, API, Razor and Blazor can coexist in the same project - but none of them shows how it's done).

I already figured out I need to extend Startup.cs by

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // This was here already
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    // I added this
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

I tried simply adding a razor page "Test" to the `Views` folder, extending the `_Layout.cshtml` by

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test">Test</a>
</li>
```

then extending `HomeController` by

```
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

However, this causes several issues with breakpoints not being hit, or the `ViewData` dictionary being `null` (with the identical code working in a pure Razor Page project), probably since it tries treating the Razor Page as an MVC view or something.

I've also tried adding something like

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Home/Test">Test</a>
</li>
```

to the layout instead, but this produces an URL like

```
https://localhost:5001/?page=%2FHome%2FTest
```

when clicking the navbar item.

I can perfectly have both things in separate VS projects, but isn't there a way to use both of them in a single VS project and a single layout?

If you want to try it out before answering, use the following steps:

1. Create a new project/solution in Visual Studio 2019
2. Select "ASP.NET Core Web Application" as project template
3. Click "Create" and select "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" as template with default settings
4. Add Razor Support in Startup.cs
5. Try to make a simple razor page working in this project

Comment: Shouldn't the pages be in the Pages folder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The razor pages does not requires a controller.

The default directory is `/Pages`, then by default all pages should be inside `Pages` directory. If you want to change it you can do it by overriding the configuration in `ConfigureServices` on startup.

```
services.AddRazorPages(c=>c.RootDirectory = "/PagesRootDir");
```

To create a link to page, you should use `asp-page` tag. For example, if the page name is `Test` the physical path (by default) will be `Pages\Test`. To generate the link, you will need to use:

```
<a asp-page="/Test">Test Page</a>
```

By default the pages won't use the default layout, you can always override it.

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.TestModel
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1>
    Test Page
</h1>
```

To remove the layout:

```
Layout = null;
```

If you want to use the "Views\Shared\_Layout" on all the pages, you will need to create a `_ViewStart` with the following code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. It allows slowly transitioning to Razor Pages without noticing anything in the front-end.

Comment: @TimMeyer why do you wanna transition to razor pages?

Comment: @cikatomo Because I evaluated the technology

Comment: You still need `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` which is missing from the answer. Otherwise good answer, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution which seems to work for now: In Startup.cs, configure razor pages to look in the /Views folder instead of it's default /Pages (this obviously breaks convention):

```
services.AddRazorPages(configure => configure.RootDirectory = "/Views");
```

Using this, I can use the `asp-page`-style nav item without adapting the controller.

I will still accept anyone's answer if you can show me how to do this without breaking default conventions (My main issue is I have no idea how to make this work with a `Pages` folder, a `Views` folder and the `_Layout.cshtml` being in only one of them.)

Comment: Working for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answers: Yes, keeping all pages under Views and changing the root directory works, but here is another option (thanks to [YiYi You in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72878208/3630657) )

Instead of using the asp-page attribute just use href="/MyRazorPage". Then the files should be in Pages/MyRazorPage/index.cshtml

In my test project, this looks like this (it also implements the _ViewStart.cshtml) from the first answer:

[image: _layout.cshtml with project structure]

This is how my .Net 6.0 program.cs file looks:
[image]