# ASP.NET Core MVC : Razor pages routing, incorrectly re-using previous route data

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm working on a dotnet 6 mvc application using RazorPages, and I'm having a problem with strange routing behavior.

I have a RazorPage /Pages/News.cshtml

This page is accessible using the default route /news

When called without any parameters this page will display an index of news articles.

I also want this page to be able to display a specific news article, via a path like this...

/news/1234-my-news-article

To achieve this, I've added a config like so...

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/News", "News/{id:regex(^\\d+\\-.*)?}");
});
```

In my templates, I can then use links like this...

```
<a asp-page="/News" asp-all-route-data="@(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "id", "1234-my-news-article" } })">My News Article</a>
```

or

```
<a asp-page="/News">All Articles</a>
```

However, once I've navigated to a specific article, the index link doesn't render correctly, and will instead link again to the same article. It appears to be re-using the current routing parameters.

Is there some way to avoid this?

update:

I've found a work-around, if I use this tag instead...

```
<a asp-page="/News" asp-route-id="">All Articles</a>
```

then it will link correctly to "/news".

It seems a bit counter-intuitive to have to explicitly set this to blank. I would have assumed it would default to unset, unless explicitly set otherwise.

Comment: `However, once I've navigated to a specific article, the index link doesn't render correctly, and will instead link again to the same article. It appears to be re-using the current routing parameters.`Can you explain more about this?You will go to `/news/1234-my-news-article` with the anchor tag,and what you do in the page?

Comment: @YiyiYou This tag <a asp-page="/News">All Articles</a> ordinarily renders to the anchor with the path "/news", however if I've linked to a specific news article, then the tag renders directly to that news article again, i.e. /News/1234-test-news-article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as ambient route values (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper#ambient-route-values), where the current route values are automatically added to outbound links which are generated by the anchor tag helper *if the destination page is the same as the current page*. In older versions of Razor Pages, this was the default behaviour for *all* pages.

As you have discovered, you can override this by setting the route value to an empty string, or as suggested elsewhere, to use a plain anchor tag for your link.

Answer (score 1):

`asp-page` tag helper will add `id` value to the route by default.It is by design.If you don't want to add it,you can try to use `href` to replace `asp-page`:

```
<a href="/News">All Articles</a>
```